# Deferred in click event with jquery for ui render

Tags: promise, openlayers-3, jquery-deferred

I have this code:

```
    $("input#drawAllRoutes").click(function (e) {
        console.log("drawAllRoutes: Start Drawing");
        showWaitPanel();

        ...
        //foreach routeElement add vector layer on map
        ...

        console.log("drawAllRoutes: Ok ");
        hideWaitPanel();
    })
```

I would have this behavior:

1. show wait panel adding the correct class in a div: this is done by showWaitPanel();
2. after that I add an high number of vector layer in openlayers3 map
3. when done, the wait panel is set hide with hideWaitPanel() that remove a class from a div

The problem is that with this code, the UI is not rendered because the vectors drawing require more resources and so freeze the UI.
So I don't see the wait panel, and the UI is freezed until the vector layers are drawed on the map.

How can I render the wait panel before the drawings?

I have read about deferred method, but I don't know very well it.

Thanks for any support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just need to force each stage into a different event thread, which can be achieved in a couple of ways.

**Using `window.setTimeout()`**

This is simple and should work despite being syntactically ugly.

```
$("input#drawAllRoutes").click(function (e) {
    console.log("drawAllRoutes: Start Drawing");
    showWaitPanel(); // assumed to be synchronous.
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        ...
        //foreach routeElement add vector layer on map
        ...
        hideWaitPanel(); // ok in same event thread unless vector rendering is itself asynchronous.
        console.log("drawAllRoutes: Ok");
    }, 0); // even with a timeout of zero seconds, the passed function will execute in a later event thread.
});
```

**Using a promise**

The nett effect here should be very similar to using `setTimeout()`, but it will work only if `showWaitPanel()` returns a promise, otherwise `showWaitPanel().then()` will throw an error. So you would need to amend your `showWaitPanel()` function.

```
$("input#drawAllRoutes").click(function (e) {
    console.log("drawAllRoutes: Start Drawing");
    showWaitPanel().then(function() {
        ...
        //foreach routeElement add vector layer on map
        ...
        hideWaitPanel(); // ok in same event thread unless vector rendering is itself asynchronous.
        console.log("drawAllRoutes: Ok");
    });
});
```

TBH, using a promise is overkill here. If it works, I would use `setTimeout()` despite its ugliness.